# How to model the message flow to and from multiple instances of the same role?

Tags: bpmn

What is the best way to model message flows to multiple instances of the same role? For example first a company creates a new contract for their business partners. After creation the company sends the contract to 10 business partners.
Each of them can accept or reject the new contract. If 8 partners will accept the contract, the company does not revise the contract.

Here is an example how the model would look like with one business partner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Multi-Instance Activities or Tasks. It's the one of several forms of looping activities. It is a shorthand and comes in two types - sequential and non-sequential. For your case non-sequential is the best fit,
this means that the activity can be completed for each item in the collection in no particular order.

Three vertical lines indicate that the multi-instance activity is non-sequential.